# Replace specific text in csv via commandline

Tags: batch-file, csv, command-line, replace, findstr

I have data in csv format that gets output from `SQL Server`. The data has some `NULL` and `N.A.` values written out which makes a column character type - it would otherwise have consisted of just integers. Is it possible via batch file statements to find and replace these values with number - say, -1 for `NULL` and -2 for `N.A.`. Here is how the data looks like now:

```
    Col A,  Col B,  Col C,  Col D,  Col E,  Col F,  Col G,  Col H
    NULL,   13,     11,     N.A.,   4710,   N.A.,   1,      1
    5,      NULL,   13,     7070,   N.A.,   4920,   N.A.,   1
    5,      NULL,   12,     8680,   N.A.,   9130,   N.A.,   1
```

I would like to convert it to this:

```
    Col A,  Col B,  Col C,  Col D,  Col E,  Col F,  Col G,  Col H
    -1,     13,     11,     -2,     4710,   -2,     1,      1
    5,      -1,     13,     7070,   -2,     4920,   -2,     1
    5,      -1,     12,     8680,   -2,     9130,   -2,     1
```

It is important to do this via batch statement as this is an intermediate output and is immediately read in by another program. I have taken a look at the `findstr` command (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) but I am usure on how to write the exact syntax and perform the replace operation. Helpful inputs much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine in front of me to be able to hack at this, but I imagine you'll need to use the `for` command to iterate over the lines in the file and modify the tokens as you output them.  You'll also want to be mindful of how `EnableDelayedExpansion` affects behavior inside the loop.  It'd be a much easier task if you could just modify the SQL query to produce the results you desire.  Also, since you're working from Windows command line consider Windows Scripting Host running `cscript`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    (for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (a.csv) do if not "%%f"=="" (
            set "line=%%f"
            set "line=!line:NULL=-1!"
            set "line=!line:N.A.=-2!"
            echo(!line!
    )) > b.csv

    endlocal
```

This will work if, as stated by OP, the file is in the format indicated, containing only integers, NULL and N.A., or at least it does not include special characters.

Comment: This one is definitely faster than @Dale's version.

Answer (score 5):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` from - https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

It should be more robust and faster.

```
type file.csv |repl "NULL" "-1" |repl "N\.A\." "-2" >newfile.csv
```

Comment: This file does the replacement really really fast!!

Comment: It's actually using `Jscript` via `Windows Scripting Host` in a hybrid batch file so it is a lot faster than batch code, and doesn't suffer from poison characters - but is still easy to use.  Aacini devised `findrepl.bat` which is a `grep`-like tool using the same technique.  dbenham wrote `repl.bat`

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDelayedExpansion

set filename=input.txt
set originalText1=NULL
set "replacedText1=-1"
set "originalText2=N.A."
set "replacedText2=-2"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %filename%') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=%%line:%originalText1%=%replacedText1%%%"
        call set "line=%%line:%originalText2%=%replacedText2%%%"
        echo !line!>> output.txt
    ) else (
        echo.
    )
)
```

This code will help you to replace all the instance of `NULL` to `-1` and `N.A.` to `-2`. The result will then be stored in `output.txt`. Hope it helps.

P.S. Note that call set is needed as it will expand the variable that is passed on the same line.

Comment: +1 for right direction, but check @MCND code performing single `>` write, instead of multiple `>>` and avoiding `type` command.