# What type of data in csv will be null after load in mysql and pandas

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have a `csv` file which contain the `null` values.
They represent in three format

1. the blank between two comma, that is  `,,`
2. the `NaN` between two comma, that is  `,NaN,`
3. the `NA` between two comma, that is  `,NA,`

I made a experiment in `pandas` and find that they would be represent as `NA` or `Nan` in `dataframe` after using the function `read_csv()`

So how can I load data into `mysql` table and make them into `null` ?

Comment: did you try `DataFrame.to_sql()` ? maybe it will convert `NA` to `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can i load data into mysql table and make them into null ?

You can use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to import the csv data to `MySQL` table. But the kind of modification in your data, you are looking for should be best done using a script.

Create a script and replace all those empty string, `NAN` and `NA` to `NULL` or just empty string in your csv file and then use that modified csv file to import to your database. Regular Expression is the option you have.

Again, depending on which OS you are using; you can do that using a single command like using `sed` on linux

```
sed 's/NAN//g' myData.csv > myNewData.csv
```

(OR) If Windows OS then take a look here [Replace specific text in csv via commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20605232/replace-specific-text-in-csv-via-commandline)

Comment: Do you mean that the unnormal value should all replaced to EMPTY STRING or NULL ?   I find that in pandas, the three types of unnormal value     are all converted to Nan or NA. If I follow your steps, the int and varchar fields which I already defined in create table step,  can all be null after loading data?

Comment: @yanachen, Yes ... those string you are trying to get rid off. First rid them off and then import.