# creating table that replaces '-' with default value during insertion

Tags: mysql, sql

I am inserting a large data from excel sheets( data contains NULL and '-' ). In database i have a table that inserts default value where there is NULL in source. I want the table should also do that for '-'

```
CREATE TABLE Data (FarmerName varchar(100) DEFAULT('defaultvalue') ,
                    FatherName varchar(100) DEFAULT('defaultvalue') ,
                   Area varchar(100) DEFAULT('defaultvalue') );
```

can anyone help. thanks

Comment: Then `ALTER` your table

Comment: What should be altered . . .?

Comment: table and his columns then you can set default value '-'

Comment: what should be changing in above query if i recreate table . can you please explain

Comment: You can do it with `CHECK`  but sorry ,CHECK constraints are not supported by MySQL

Comment: @Sami, check will fail the insert

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz did you read my comment well? isay not supported

Comment: can I use replace function during insertion ?

Comment: @sami, Yes that was the point. Even if it was supported it wouldn't be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are one of these is a valid option for you?

1. Load to a staging table and then use INSERT INTO .. SELECT ...
2. Create a view that masks '-' and work against the view and not directly against the table.
3. Add a virtual column that masks '-'

---

#### Demo

Setup

```
create table t (id int,c1 varchar (100),c2 varchar(100));
```

---

**Solution 1**

Setup

```
create table t_stg (id int identity,c1 varchar (100),c2 varchar(100));
```

Flow

```
truncate table t_stg;

-- This insert simulates the bulk load
insert into t_stg (id,c1,c2) values (1,'A','-'),(2,'-','B'),(3,'-','-');

insert into t (id,c1,c2)    
select  id
       ,case when c1 = '-' then 'DEF_C1' else c1 end  as c1
       ,case when c2 = '-' then 'DEF_C2' else c2 end  as c2
from    t_stg 
;
```

Use

```
select * from t;

+----+--------+--------+
| id | c1     | c2     |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | A      | DEF_C2 |
+----+--------+--------+
| 2  | DEF_C1 | B      |
+----+--------+--------+
| 3  | DEF_C1 | DEF_C2 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

**Solution 2**

Setup

```
create view t_v
as
select  id
   ,case when c1 = '-' then 'DEF_C1' else c1 end  as c1
   ,case when c2 = '-' then 'DEF_C2' else c2 end  as c2
from    t_stg 
;
```

Flow

```
-- This insert simulates the bulk load
insert into t(id,c1,c2) values (1,'A','-'),(2,'-','B'),(3,'-','-');
```

Use

```
select * from t_v;

+----+--------+--------+
| id | c1     | c2     |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | A      | DEF_C2 |
+----+--------+--------+
| 2  | DEF_C1 | B      |
+----+--------+--------+
| 3  | DEF_C1 | DEF_C2 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

**Solution 3**

setup

```
alter table t add c1_v varchar(100) generated always as (case when c1 = '-' then 'DEF_C1' else c1 end) virtual;
alter table t add c2_v varchar(100) generated always as (case when c2 = '-' then 'DEF_C2' else c2 end) virtual;
```

Flow

```
-- This insert simulates the bulk load
insert into t(id,c1,c2) values (1,'A','-'),(2,'-','B'),(3,'-','-');
```

Use

```
select * from t;

+----+----+----+--------+--------+
| id | c1 | c2 | c1_v   | c2_v   |
+----+----+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | A  | -  | A      | DEF_C2 |
+----+----+----+--------+--------+
| 2  | -  | B  | DEF_C1 | B      |
+----+----+----+--------+--------+
| 3  | -  | -  | DEF_C1 | DEF_C2 |
+----+----+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I have different default values for different columns .
like
CREATE TABLE Data (
FarmerName varchar(100) DEFAULT('defaultvalue1') ,
FatherName varchar(100) DEFAULT('defaultvalue2') ,
Area varchar(100) DEFAULT('defaultvalue3') );

Comment: Where do you find this to be an issue?

Comment: answered accepted . can you please explain about staging table . I am writing code in c# and can not load(stage) complete table in Datatable as it contains a very large data

Answer (score 0):

> I want the table should also do that for '-'

Then modify your excel or csv file and replace all occurrences of `-` with `NULL` and use that modified file for importing probably using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

Modifying can easily be done either using a command (OR) using a script depending on which OS you are running on. See this answer for that information [What type of data in csv will be null after load in mysql and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887171/what-type-of-data-in-csv-will-be-null-after-load-in-mysql-and-pandas/40887262#40887262)

Per your comment *not allowed to change source data...*
Then a possible alternative (may not be a solution) would be having a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` on that table and replace those `-` with `NULL` in trigger logic and perform the `INSERT` but it will have adverse effect for bulk insert which is your case (moreover, this kind of recursive trigger is not supported in `MySQL`)